# Which is a better Get member method?

Tags: c++, class, vector, stdvector, accessor

I have a class which has a member of type `std:vector`

```
  private:
     std::vector<int> myVector;
```

I have created Get method to access `myVector`

```
1. const std::vector<int>   GetMyVector() const;
2. const void   GetMyVector(std::vector<int>& vec) const;
```

The implementations are as follows respectively:

```
1. const std::vector<int> MyClass::GetMyVector() const
   {
       return  myVector;
   }

2. const void MyClass::GetMyVector(std::vector<int>& vec) const
   {
       vec =  myVector;
   }
```

Which one of the two Get methods is better and why?

Comment: 1st option copy the vector, which is not the idea of get. 2nd option allow to have a write access to myVector after the function call...

Comment: Do you want the caller to have their own copy of the vector, or do you want them to have access access the data member?

Comment: @juanchopanza Purpose is just to access the member. No copy intended.

Comment: OK, neither of your methods are doing that, so they are both poor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Guess I should go with simonc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd prefer option 3:

```
const std::vector<int>& MyClass::GetMyVector() const
{
    return  myVector;
}
```

Your option 1 returned a copy of `myVector`.  This returns a const (so read-only) reference to the class member.

Comment: Maybe they *want* to return a copy.

Comment: @simonc Somewhere I read that if the return from a function is an aggregate, it should be by reference output parameter rather than by return. Is that true?

Comment: @ontherocks No, that is not true.

Comment: @ontherocks: depends what you mean by "should". If that's what it says in the style guide for a project you're working on, then you should follow it even if it's wrong for general purposes. However, "aggregate" is a technical term in C++ and `vector` is not an aggregate.

Comment: @juanchopanza True but I'd find the function name a bit misleading in that case.  Couldn't clients who wanted a copy handle this via `std::vector<int> copy(myClass->GetMyVector());` ?

Comment: The point is that it was not clear that OP wanted to expose their data member like that. But apparently they do.

Comment: @juanchopanza: By the "exposition" stand point, returning a copy or a const reference does not change the level of encapsulation: in both the cases you view the data and cannot modify them.   By an efficiency standpoint, returning a const& avoids to create a copy. If you assign that const& to another vector (like `v = m.GetMyVector()`) the copy will be made just there. In practice, the idea is avoid the copy, unless specifically needed.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Of course there are different levels of encapsulation (assuming the reference is to a data member). A reference and a value are completely different things. The fact that the caller cannot modify the data via the reference does not change the fact that they have a reference to something that may change or even disappear.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's true is you STORE the reference. If you return it it will just be a temporary that disapper (the reference) at the ";". Whether it will become persistent or will become a copy depends on what you assign it to / use it to initialize what.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia It's better (in the general case) to prevent the caller from storing a reference to something that may disappear, rather than place the responsibility on the caller not to store the  reference. This is basic OO software design principles (and as such they don't apply in every case of course).

Comment: @Snps: The is no "better" without a context (and there is no such "genral case": C++ is not pure OOP, so you cannot assume OOP works fine everywhere). Is it better to go upstairs or downstairs ? Let OO principle to find the answer, if you like them. I prefer to remain atheist and agnostic. Probably the two worst thing you can imagine.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Lets not get philosophical on the matter :) There IS a limited context and there IS a better *practice* IMO as it usually leads to the least amount of problems (you can say that without implying that it's true in all cases). The OP uses classes and private members and thus OOP is relevant. That last part of your comment: are you saying that I believe in god? :)

Comment: @snps: No, I am saying i don't want to believe in the OOP vangelis. The use of class and data protection is not tailored to OOP only.

Answer (score 1):

Why return the vector at all?

```
int MyClass::GetItem(const size_t index) const
{
    return myVector[index];
}
```

Comment: Avoids adding `GetSize`, `Begin`, `End`, etc too. The Law of Demeter sometimes improves things and sometimes makes them worse.

Comment: @SteveJessop It all depends on what the vector will be used for, of course.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are exposing your implementation when you return a private member of a class from a member function, which usually is bad design. Take a look at @JoachimPileborg's solution for an example of how to avoid this.

If you want to return a *copy* then you should return by value.

If you want to return a reference to an object then return by reference. **However**, bear in mind that when the object is destructed you will end up with a dangling reference, e.g.

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<int>& getVec() {
        return myVec;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> myVec;
};

int main() {
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    std::vector<int>& myRef = f->getVec();
    delete f;

    std::cout << myRef.size(); // The demons come! Dangling reference!
}
```

Because of this, it is often the right thing to return a copy instead of a reference.

Comment: ... "which usually is bad design"...

That's just a prejudice. There is simply not enough context, here, to say anything about the overall design.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I disagree, design principles is a good practice to follow, especially when you don't have enough experience to foresee later issues. Design principles are meant to be applied in limited context, so you can abstract your overall design. In this case, exposing the implementation creates a rigid design as changes to the class (e.g. change of container type) will require changes in every other class that uses the function.

Comment: Every design can be good to something and bad to something else. Design principles are not outside the information theory physics. There are many "pattern" as many "anti-pattern".  One anti-pattern is the "over-engineering": it happens when a principle is forced to be followed even when the context is not needing it. None of us can evaluate that being context information completely missing.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia As we're talking object-oriented programming and the class is not an aggregate, exposing private members of a class is an indication of an anti-pattern. The response would be: you shouldn't do it. I think calling it "over-engineering" because of lacking context is an exaggeration resulting from your own experience, which is not necessarily the best advice to give to beginners. My previous comment still applies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning an object by copy then there is no any sense to declare it as const. So instead of

```
const std::vector<int> MyClass::GetMyVector() const
{
    return  myVector;
}
```

I would write

```
std::vector<int> MyClass::GetMyVector() const
{
    return  myVector;
}
```

The second declaration is worst than the first one because it only confuses users. It is not clear whether the corresponding data member of the class is assigned to the parameter or this method makes some changes of the parameter without assigning the corresponding data member  to the parameter.

So considering suggested variants by you I would choise declaration

```
std::vector<int> MyClass::GetMyVector() const
{
    return  myVector;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As a rule of thumb always try to return `const reference` of a class member .
So use `const std::vector<int> & MyClass::GetMyVector() const`